# UDP Tracker Protocol using Akka

Tags: scala, udp, akka, bittorrent

I am trying to implement BitTorrent Udp Tracker Protocol using Akka IO module. The first step in the protocol is to send 16 byte payload to tracker as mentioned [here](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/udp_tracker_protocol.html). I am not able to receive data in return. Any help is much appreciated.

```
package tracker

import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import java.nio.ByteOrder

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.io.Udp.Event
import akka.io.{IO, Udp}
import akka.util.ByteString

object udpTest extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem("UDPTest")

  val (listenPort, sendPort) = (6960, 80)
  val url = "udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com"
  val listenerActor1: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props
  (new Listener(listenPort, sendPort, url)))

  implicit val networkOrder = ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN
  //  0x41727101980 = 4497486125440
  val payLoad: ByteString = ByteString.newBuilder.putLong("4497486125440".toLong)
    .putInt(0).putInt(scala.util.Random.nextInt).result

  Thread.sleep(1000)
  listenerActor1 ! payLoad

}

object DataSent extends Event

class Listener(listenPort: Int, sendPort: Int, url: String) extends Actor {

  IO(Udp)(context.system) ! Udp.Bind(self,
    new InetSocketAddress("localhost", listenPort))

  def receive = {
    case Udp.Bound(local) =>
      println(s"Listening on $listenPort")
      context.become(ready(sender()))
  }

  def ready(socket: ActorRef): Receive = {
    case Udp.Received(data, remote) =>
      println(s"Response Received ${data.map(b => "%02x" format b).mkString}")
    case payLoad: ByteString =>
      println(s"Sending payload ${payLoad.map(b => "%02x" format b).mkString}")
      socket ! Udp.Send(payLoad, new InetSocketAddress(url, sendPort), DataSent)
    case Udp.Unbind => socket ! Udp.Unbind
    case Udp.Unbound => context.stop(self)
    case DataSent => println("Data is sent")
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by not being able to receive data. Do you get any errors? How do you send the data to your service?

Comment: I send payload message to actor it in turn sends payload to `url` at `sendPort`. No I am not getting any errors. so If I am able to send payload to tracker I get acknowledgement here **DataSent** and also reply from tracker as mentioned [here](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/udp_tracker_protocol.html) , but I am not getting such acknowledgement. To check whether my logic is correct or not I replaced `url` with `localhost` and `sendPort = listenPort` I am getting acknowledgement in this case.

Comment: The tracker: udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80 is down and has been so for a long time. Try use udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969 or udp://tracker.leechers-paradise.org:6969

Comment: Yeah, I tried with other trackers as well but I am not able to send payload and receive response.

Comment: Then maybe try using WireShark and compare with a working client.

Comment: Yes, I even tried that payload is same except for connection Id part which is random.

Comment: It would be easier to help, if you posted relevant data as the payload. Be aware that in the **"connect request"**, the  **0x0000041727101980** is a **protocol_id**, not a arbitrary **connection_id**

Comment: A correct **connect request** is: **0x000004172710198000000000TTTTTTTT** where **TTTTTTTT** is a random **transaction_id**

Comment: Yeah, here is a sample payload I am sending `0x000004172710198000000000f702bcf9`